# Disallow Twitter Bootstrap modal window from closing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, mouseclick-event

I am creating a modal window using Twitter Bootstrap. The default behavior is if you click outside the modal area, the modal will automatically close. I would like to disable that -- i.e. not close the modal window when clicking outside the modal.

Can someone share jQuery code to do this?

Comment: You may have a perfectly valid reason for doing this (and there are likely many others). However, it's worth noting that in general, UX considerations would advise against this--most users expect that clicking out of a modal will bring the content "below" to the "front."

Comment: @Trevor That's like the opposite of [modal](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window).

Comment: what if, if there is a page at the background that can only be activated only if the user login first. By clicking the modal Ok button the user will be redirected to the login page. If the user can just clicking out, this means that the user skip the login page and just accessing the page without login. All Hell Break Loose

Comment: @Trevor I don't see any evidence at all to support your claim.

Comment: The feature is sensible in a scenario when the user has to fill out many form fields in the modal.  If the user accidentally clicks outside of the modal, then all of the entered details would be lost; then they would have to reactivate the modal and refill the fields.  This feature would avoid such an irritation.

Answer (score 720, accepted):

I believe you want to set the **backdrop value** to **static**. If you want to avoid the window to close when using the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, you have to set another value.

Example:

```
<a data-controls-modal="your_div_id"
   data-backdrop="static"
   data-keyboard="false"
   href="#">
```

OR if you are using JavaScript:

```
$('#myModal').modal({
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false
});
```

Comment: @user1296175 What was your final code to achieve this? I want to do the same.

Comment: Thank you @nobita, add data-backdrop="static" does the trick! Twitter bootstrap document is poor :(

Comment: Check answer from @@Varun Chatterji and include this on your modal definition

Comment: disable out-side click for all modals with single line of js:
 $.fn.modal.Constructor.DEFAULTS.backdrop = 'static';

Comment: There is an issue with this if you are using it for a login modal
Any user can add a close button <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
To the modal - live and just close it

Comment: This also disables the controls on the background. Is there a way to keep other controls active but just let the modal not close ?

Comment: Add these attributes to the modal's container div and not the triggering button or anchor !

Comment: For Angular users: var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modalTemplate.html',
      controller: 'modalController',
      backdrop: 'static',
    });

Comment: I found the show/hide behaviour changed when I just added the `backdrop` and `keyboard` values via javascript, but was able to fix that by additionally specifying `show`, as posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41293550/1294318).

Comment: I used the version in the comment from Lukas to disable it across all dialogs, but had to use this on Bootstrap 4: $.fn.modal.Constructor.Default.backdrop = 'static';

Answer (score 313):

Just set the `backdrop` property to `'static'`.

```
$('#myModal').modal({
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: true
})
```

You may also want to set the `keyboard` property to `false` because that prevents the modal from being closed by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key on the keyboard.

```
$('#myModal').modal({
  backdrop: 'static',
  keyboard: false
})
```

`myModal` is the ID of the div that contains your modal content.

Comment: Yep, this is the cleanest, simplest answer (since it avoids adding data attributes). For reference, `backdrop` and `keyboard` are mentioned [here in their documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) under the _Options_ section.

Comment: Are data attributes something to be avoided? Kindly guide on this.

Comment: @GopalAggarwal: Depends on how you setup the modal. If you associate a modal to multiple anchor tags, then using data attributes might make sense. But when there is just one modal per tag, I would go with the script parameters where every behaviour is visible in one place.

Comment: Also to avoid modal displaying immediately pass in show: false

Answer (score 224):

You can also include these attributes in the modal definition itself:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
```

Comment: Yep, this is the cleanest, simplest answer (since it works by adding data attributes). For reference, backdrop and keyboard are mentioned here in their documentation under the Options section.

Comment: If you launch modal on page load this is the best way to remove other closing options.

Answer (score 47):

If you already have initialized the modal window, then you may want to reset the options with `$('#myModal').removeData("modal").modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})` to make sure it will apply the new options.

Comment: This helped me out. After setting the "backdrop: 'static'" the user could still close the modal with a click; seemed like a bug, but this did the trick!

Comment: For now: $('#modal').removeData('bs.modal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});

Answer (score 37):

Override the Bootstrap ‘hide’ event of Dialog and stop its default behavior (to dispose the dialog).

Please see the below code snippet:

```
   $('#yourDialogID').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {

       e.preventDefault();
   });
```

It works fine in our case.

Comment: then, how to revert it?

Comment: Just elegant. thx :)

And @sertaconay just create a boolean variable (for instance) which will be checked to decide if u want to prevent the default

Comment: only option here that worked after a modal was opend

Comment: This is a perfect solution if you want to have finer control over when modals are closable and when they're not.

Answer (score 33):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
<div id="myModal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true"
     data-backdrop="static"  data-keyboard="false">
```

Comment: This is perfect for a case where the modal is declared in the html, and only opened via javascript - ie there is no link to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Kind of like @AymKdn's answer, but this will allow you to change the options without re-initializing the modal.

```
$('#myModal').data('modal').options.keyboard = false;
```

Or if you need to do multiple options, JavaScript's `with` comes in handy here!

```
with ($('#myModal').data("modal").options) {
    backdrop = 'static';
    keyboard = false;
}
```

If the modal is already open, these options will only take effect the *next time* the modal is opened.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030448/convert-a-twitter-bootstrap-uncloseable-modal-into-a-closeable-one But I dont like this solution though

Answer (score 14):

Just add these two things

```
data-backdrop="static" 
data-keyboard="false"
```

It will look like this now

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

It will disable the escape button and also the click anywhere and hide.

Comment: This advice was provided years earlier.

Answer (score 11):

You can disable the background's click-to-close behavior and make this the default for all your modals by adding this JavaScript to your page (make sure it is executed after jQuery and Bootstrap JS are loaded):

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.DEFAULTS.backdrop = 'static';
});
```

Answer (score 6):

As D3VELOPER says, the following code resolve it:

```
$('#modal').removeData('bs.modal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
```

I'm using both jquery & bootstrap and simply `removeData('modal')` don't work.

Answer (score 5):

##### [bs 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#static-backdrop)

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
  Launch static backdrop modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```

##### [bs 4.4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#static-backdrop)

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
  Launch static backdrop modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The best I found is add this code to the link

```
<!-- Link -->
<a href="#mdl" role="button"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-toggle="modal" id_team="" ></a>
<-- Div -->
<div id="mdl" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing that is very easy nowadays. Just add:

```
data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
```

In your modal divider.

Comment: This advice was provided years earlier on this same page.

Answer (score 3):

Attribute names have changed in Bootstrap 5. You can use the following :

```
data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false"
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone comes here from Google trying to figure out how to prevent someone from closing a modal, don't forget that there's also a close button on the top right of the modal that needs to be removed.

I used some CSS to hide it:

```
#Modal .modal-header button.close {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Note that using "display: none;" gets overwritten when the modal is created, so don't use that.

Comment: Can you not also just remove the button from the modal-header?

Comment: Sometimes it's beneficial to use CSS instead of altering the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to conditionally disable the `backdrop click closing` feature. You can use the following line to set the `backdrop` option to `static` during runtime.

**Bootstrap v3.xx**

```
jQuery('#MyModal').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
```

**Bootstrap v2.xx**

```
jQuery('#MyModal').data('modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
```

This will prevent an already instantiated model with `backdrop` option set to `false` (*the default behavior*), from closing.

Answer (score 2):

You can set default behavior of modal popup by using of below line of code:

```
 $.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.DEFAULTS.backdrop = 'static';
```

Comment: like +1 this method, I don't want that option for all modals.

Answer (score 2):

The updated syntax according to bootstrap 5 is as followed.
[Reference Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/)

```html
<div class="modal fade" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is another solution that some of you guys might be looking for (as I was..)

My problem was similar, the modal box was closing while the iframe I had inside was loading, so I had to disable the modal dismiss until the Iframe finishes loading, then re-enable.

The solutions presented here were not working 100%.

My solution was this:

```
showLocationModal = function(loc){

    var is_loading = true;

    if(is_loading === true) {

        is_loading  = false;
        var $modal   = $('#locationModal');

        $modal.modal({show:true});

        // prevent Modal to close before the iframe is loaded
        $modal.on("hide", function (e) {
            if(is_loading !== true) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false
            }
        });

        // populate Modal
        $modal.find('.modal-body iframe').hide().attr('src', location.link).load(function(){

            is_loading = true;
     });
}};
```

So I temporarily prevent the Modal from closing with:

```
$modal.on("hide", function (e) {
    if(is_loading !== true) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false
    }
});
```

But ith the var is_loading that will re enable closing after the Iframe has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="myBtn3">Static 
Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Static Backdrop</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>You cannot click outside of this modal to close it.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
      dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
   <script>
    $("#myBtn3").click(function(){
     $("#myModal3").modal({backdrop: "static"});
    });
   });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To Update the backdrop state in Bootstrap 4.1.3 after the modal have been Display, We used the following line from [Bootstrap-Modal-Wrapper](https://github.com/JavaTMP/bootstrap-modal-wrapper) plugin. [Plugin Repository code reference](https://github.com/JavaTMP/bootstrap-modal-wrapper/blob/9bc20ad14e46ca372d9750245538e2c998a184b5/js/bootstrap-modal-wrapper-factory.js#L309).

```
$("#yourModalElement").data('bs.modal')._config.backdrop = (true : "static");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try main line with:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="verifyModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

  $("#modalId").modal({
     backdrop: 'static',
     keyboard: false,
     show: false
  });

});
```

"backdrop:'static'" will prevent closing modal when clicking outside of it;
"keyboard: false" specifies that the modal can be closed from escape key (Esc)
"show: false" will hide the modal when the page has finished loading

Answer (score 0):

The solution presented as an answer does not work, what is wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.modal').modal('show');
            $('.modal').modal({
              backdrop: 'static',
              keyboard: false
            })
        });
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/octicons@8.5.0/index.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
       <body>
       
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="text-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">print</button></div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post this as a new question, not as an answer to an existing question.  Your new question can reference this original post.

Answer (score 0):

`When backdrop is set to static, the modal will not close when clicking outside it. Click the button below to try it. use data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" for bootstrap 5 and data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" for bootstrap 4`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4 CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container p-5" >
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          When backdrop is set to static, the modal will not close when clicking outside it. Click the button below to try it. use data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false"
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-4" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
            Launch static backdrop 5 modal
          </button>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          When backdrop is set to static, the modal will not close when clicking outside it. Click the button below to try it. use data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            Launch static backdrop 4 modal
          </button>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
          data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div> 
    
    <!-- Bootstrap 5 Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `static` for `backdrop` option (backdrop: 'static'). And prevent closing the modal by pressing `Esc` from `keyboard` you have to set `false` for `keyboard` option (keyboard: false)

So, the code will be.

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq('#exampleModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobita's answer works for single cases, but I have like 20-30 modals on an old site and was looking for an answer that set this for every modal opened with bootstrap.

You can target the [event namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) for the modal and add in default settings for every bootstrap modal.

You might not want to do this for every modal but in case you did, there's no need to statically specify each modal call.

```
$(document).on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this)
    var href = $this.attr('href')
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''))) //strip for ie7
    var option = $target.data('modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({ remote:!/#/.test(href) && href }, $target.data(), $this.data(), {backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})

    e.preventDefault()

    $target
      .modal(option)
      .one('hide', function () {
        $this.focus()
      })
})
```

In my case, I added `{backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}` to the option structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 5 or above, use the below code in modal div

```
<div class="modal fade customModal customModalForm" id="editPartySetting" data-bs-keyboard="false" data-bs-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editSettings"
aria-hidden="true" >
```

This will restrict user, now popup won't get closed by 'Esc' button and by clicking outside.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 5 or later, it's recommended to use `data-bs-backdrop` and `data-bs-keyboard`. If you are using Bootstrap 4 or an earlier version, you can use `data-backdrop` and `data-keyboard`. Ensure that you are using the correct attribute based on the version of Bootstrap you are working with.

v5

```
 data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false"
```

v4

```
 data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#static-backdrop