# Bootstrap modal dismiss if user click anywhere else..how to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter's Bootstrap modal.

The modal is dismissed whenever the user clicks anywhere else on the screen except the modal.

Is there a way I can prevent this, so the user has to click the Close button to dismiss the modal?

Best,

Comment: Check the docs under "options": http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disallow Twitter Bootstrap modal window from closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894339/disallow-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window-from-closing)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

you can pass these options:

```
{
  keyboard: false,
  backdrop: 'static'
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the next answer for bootstrap 4

Answer (score 65):

In most cases, the modal dialog is constructed not using Javascript, rather it's using the markup, in this scenario, just add attribute: data-backdrop="static" in the div that has class="modal fade".

Example:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Don't forget `data-keyboard="false"` if you want to disable close using escape key.

Comment: The best answer!

Answer (score 7):

In some cases, this alternative solution may be useful.

```
$('#modalElement').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For new version of bootstrap at least 5.0 the correct way is:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="carDialog" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="carDialogLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Take a look at backdrop and keyboard it is: data-bs-backdrop and data-bs-keyboard.