# Prevent Bootstrap Modal from disappearing when clicking outside or pressing escape?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap modal as a wizard window, and would like to prevent the user from closing it when clicking outside of the modal or when pressing escape. Instead, I want it to be closed when the user presses the finish button. How could I achieve this scenario?

Comment: thx, i could not found it !?

Comment: Already provided solution, please see the link below:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894339/disallow-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window-from-closing/25159755#25159755

Comment: In ant design, you can simply use `maskClosable={false}`

Answer (score 1102, accepted):

If using JavaScript then:

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})
```

in case of 'show'

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}, 'show');
```

or in HTML:

```
<a data-controls-modal="your_div_id" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#">
```

Comment: When using javascript you will have to set keyboard to false to prevent closing by pressing ESC too.

Comment: note that the tabulation is still enabled in the background

Comment: does the html belong on the trigger? or on the modal [has the modal_id]?

Comment: I usualy use $("#myModal").modal("show"); how do i make it not to fade away while clicking outside the modal @Eshan Ershadi

Comment: I have added `data-backdrop="static"` to my modal's HTML, and it is working with BS 3.x.

Comment: it's not working with my modal. f

Comment: JS solution doesn't work, HTML solution works!

Comment: I am using React with Bootrap model but sorry to say, this solution does not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: the js solution opened the modal with the page load

Comment: I have tried with  __ $('#myModal').modal({keyboard: false}) __ before and didn't work. But trying with this solution worked, so seems to be something funny with this component, because you need to add __ backdrop __ attribute to make it works.

Comment: 2022 solution: ```data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false"```

Comment: As @Laurie97275 said : in bootstrap 5 it worked by adding data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#static-backdrop

Comment: Working fine for me. Good work!

Answer (score 328):

Works too, `data-backdrop="static"` to click out and `data-keyboard="false"` to Esc in your div modal:

```
<div id="idModal" class="modal hide" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
```

Comment: The other suggestions are correct if you need to set this programmatically/runtime, but this is the right way of doing it design-time and I think is the best way for "separation-of-concerns"-minded devs.

Comment: I had two modals in a single page. At least one of them never worked right. But this solution solves it. Also it makes sense to put it in the modal div itself.

Comment: if you are thinking of using this method and the modal for multiple purposes - perhaps one of which you do want them to be able to click on background to close. Maybe better to use the '.modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})' option, when you don't want to allow - and '.modal('toggle')' when you DO want to allow. If not and you use this method - you will need to use js to allow for backdrop click close anyway

Answer (score 89):

You can Use Direct in bootstrap model also.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
```

Answer (score 43):

> Just add `data-backdrop="static"` and `data-keyboard="false"` attributes to that modal.

Eg.

```
<a data-controls-modal="your_div_id" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#">
```

Answer (score 31):

```
<button class='btn btn-danger fa fa-trash' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal' data-backdrop='static' data-keyboard='false'></button>
```

simply add data-backdrop and data-keyboard attribute to your button on which model is open.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your suggestion. I am using React with Bootstrap model but this solution does not work for me. Thank.

Answer (score 27):

You can use the code below

```
$.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.DEFAULTS.backdrop = 'static';
```

to change the default behavior.

Comment: In BS4 it shows that `.DEFAULTS` is "undefined". There is a `.Default` however, and  doing  `...Default.backdrop = 'static'` seems to work.

Answer (score 24):

```
$('#modal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}, 'show');
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer does not work. You have to set the options before show the modal. `$('#modal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}, 'show');`

Answer (score 19):

I use these attributes and it works, `data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"`

Comment: I use don't work. please write all of tags.

Answer (score 15):

***This code will prevent the modal from closing if you click outside the modal.***

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal({
           backdrop: 'static',
           keyboard: false
    })
   });
```

Answer (score 12):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
```

Answer (score 9):

The following script worked for me:

```
// prevent event when the modal is about to hide
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: And how did you close it. If you want to close after this?

Comment: Actually the modal is opened inside a browser window or in dialog like jQuery UI dialog. So if we let the modal close, the window or dialog will be empty. I know this is not the proper design, but really helpful when a feature designed as modal of site B is needed to be opened/showed inside of site A!

Comment: @Prateekro if you define the handler as a function and pass that in instead of an anonymous function you can pass that to jQuery's `unbind` function  to remove a specific event handler. This way the existing `hide.bs.modal` handler will continue to work.

Answer (score 6):

If you need disable clicking outside but enable pressing escape

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',   // This disable for click outside event
    keyboard: true        // This for keyboard event
})
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need to setup this *after* the modal is shown, you can use @Nabid solution. However, sometimes you still need to allow *some* method to close the modal. Assuming you have a button with class `really-close-the-modal`, which should really close the modal, you can use this code (jquery):

```
var closeButtonClicked = false;

$('.really-close-the-modal').on('click', function () {
    closeButtonClicked = true;
});

$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if (!closeButtonClicked) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    closeButtonClicked = false;
});
```

This isn't really nice code design, but it helped me in a situation where the modal was shown with a loader animation, until an ajax request returned, and only then could I know if the modal needed to be configured to prevent "implicit" closing. You can use a similar design to prevent closing the modal while it's still loading.

Answer (score 3):

You should use backdrop static , keyboard false. and can use close button off by using jQuery or can remove from modal html. Hope this help.

```
 $('#MyModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
    $('#MyModal .close').css('display','none');
```

Comment: $('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working when i click out side the modal, but if i use html **`input`** field inside modal-body then focus your cursor on that input then press **`esc`** key the modal has closed.
Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4EUS6/185/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal show">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">     

    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>

  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

i think this codepen  can help you
[prevent modal close css and bootstrap](http://codepen.io/shubhangisingh/pen/RKbeqV)