# how to create Bootstrap static modal that does NOT dissapear and loads by default

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to create a view in codeignitor for a log in page that permanently displays a Bootstrap Modal. I am able to get the modal pop up window by adding the button, but I do not know how to get the modal to display by default when the page  loads.

I copied and pasted the following from the docs but nothing shows on the page, it only shows up in the source.

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>       

    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Answer (score 16):

Open the modal by javascript on document ready by `$('#myModal').modal('show');`

Set backdrop and keyboard to false prevent the modal closing when clicking outside it.

```
$(function() {
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop:false,keyboard:false});
$('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop:'static',keyboard:false, show:true});
```

Or set the backdrop to static, from the docs: "Alternatively, specify static for a backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click.", see also [Prevent Bootstrap Modal from disappearing when clicking outside or pressing escape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152073/prevent-bootstrap-modal-from-disappearing-when-clicking-outside-or-pressing-esca)

Comment: The best answer!

Answer (score 15):

You can create this by removing `fade` and add `show` class to modal.

```
<div class="modal show">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

### [Check the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qzJLx/1/)

Comment: Thankd so much for this you have no idea how much time you have saved me

Comment: What would be the cleanest way to make the area outside the modal darken in this case?

Comment: @frostshoxx I ended up settling for a hidden button with a setTimtout click: https://jsfiddle.net/LeoTM/ajw7xh8f/5/

Answer (score 4):

To make modal undismissable you can set backdrop static without javascript:

```
 <div class="modal" data-backdrop="static" ... >
```

Open onload using:

```
$('#your_modal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Does not work when initializing in Javascript (at least not with Bootstrap 4). You then need to pass it as option in js call