# yii2 bootstrap modal hide show

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, yii2

I am using yii2 bootstrap model to show some data on that and 
bootstrap model is close through two ways,

1)on click of model close button.

2)on click of that black area which is appeared in background like light-box.

I already handle the close button event but unable to handle that black area click event.
I don't want to close my model while click on that black area how should i do that.Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

My model

```
<?php 
Modal::begin([
    'header' => 'Student Info',
    'id' => 'stud-info',
    'closeButton' => ['id' => 'close-button'],      
    ]); 

    $form->field($model, 'StudName',
        [
        'options'=>['enableAjaxValidation' => false]
        ])->textInput();

 Modal::end();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For preventing closing when clicking on black area use:

```
'backdrop' => 'static',
```

There is another way of closing - by clicking `Esc` button. It can be prevented like that:

```
'keyboard' => false,
```

You should put these options under [clientOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-widget.html#$clientOptions-detail) section like that:

```
'clientOptions' => [
    ...
],
```

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152073/prevent-bootstrap-modal-from-disappearing-when-clicking-outside-or-pressing-esca) for details.

No need to write additional javascript for events to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following method:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

For more details please refer [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

Comment: If you still decided to use event to handle this, alternatively you can specify it via [clientEvents](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-widget.html#$clientEvents-detail) property.