# Prevent Bootstrap Modal from disappearing when clicking outside or pressing escape

Tags: javascript, jquery

I consulted some more solutions, but my code doesn't work:

[Prevent Bootstrap Modal from disappearing when clicking outside or pressing escape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152073/prevent-bootstrap-modal-from-disappearing-when-clicking-outside-or-pressing-esca)

[Disallow Twitter Bootstrap modal window from closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894339/disallow-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window-from-closing/64575145?noredirect=1#comment114182723_64575145)

my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.modal').modal('show');
            $('.modal').modal({
              backdrop: 'static',
              keyboard: false
            })
        });
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/octicons@8.5.0/index.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
       <body>
       
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="text-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">print</button></div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding the `show` before configuration, the modal that opens isn't seeing your configuration. If you remove your show, you can just chain it to the modal call with the configuration.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            
            $('.modal').modal({
              backdrop: 'static',
              keyboard: false
            }).show()
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

       
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="text-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">print</button></div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```