# Bootstrap 5 Static Modal Still Closes when I Click Outside

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a page that checks if the user is currently logged in before he can do anything else. If the user is not logged in, the login modal loads and the user should not be able to do anything else unless he logs in. So far, this is what is working:

```
function checkrater(){
            var rater=document.getElementById("initials").value;
            if(rater.length <=0)
            {
                var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('loginModal'), {})
                myModal.toggle()
            }               
        }
```

and the HTML is this:

```
<body style="padding:5px;" onload="checkrater();">    
<div class="modal fade show" style="display: block;" id="loginModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Please login</h5>              
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">                
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I am using bootstrap 5 for my CSS and the modal loads perfectly. My problem is when I click outside the modal, it still hides. I don't know if I did something wrong because I already tried it on another page and it still does not work. I tried it in Chrome and Firefox but got the same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Bootstrap Modal from disappearing when clicking outside or pressing escape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152073/prevent-bootstrap-modal-from-disappearing-when-clicking-outside-or-pressing-esca)

Comment: I'm sorry, but No. The suggestions there (data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false") are already in my code that is why I am asking if I did something wrong because somehow it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're using Bootstrap 5, but the syntax is of Bootstrap 4. All the `data-*` attributes of Bootstrap 4 are now `data-bs-*` in Bootstrap 5 to help the user identify their own `data-*` from Bootstrap's.

So in your code, change `data-static` to `data-bs-static` & `data-keyboard` to `data-bs-keyboard` and your code should work fine.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for this. Its working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

for more clarification

bootstrap 4

```
data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"
```

bootstrap 5

```
data-bs-keyboard="false" data-bs-backdrop="static"
```