Vue+Bootstrap: Prevent modal closing with a flag
I have a modal component that displays a form:
<template>
<div ref="modal" class="modal fade" :id="id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title h5">New Ladder</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close"
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
            <div ref="alert"></div>
            <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="mb-1">
                        <label for="addLadderName" class="form-label" hidden>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addLadderName" placeholder="Enter name"
                               v-model.trim="addLadderForm.name"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary me-auto"
                            data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        {{ processing ? 'One moment please...' : 'Create' }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

On submission, I set the processing flag to true, and set it back to false once I receive a response from the server.
const modal = ref(null);
const alert = ref(null);
const processing = ref(false);

const addLadderForm = reactive({name: ''});

function handleSubmit() {
  if (processing.value) {
    return;
  }
  processing.value = true
  const payload = {
    name: addLadderForm.name,
  };
  addLadder(payload);
}

function addLadder(payload) {
  const path = 'http://localhost:5001/new-ladder';
  axios.post(path, payload)
    .then(() => {
      processing.value = false;
      Modal.getInstance(modal.value).hide();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      showAlert('danger', error.toString());
      processing.value = false;
    });
}

While waiting for the server response, I would like to force the modal to stay open, even if the user attempts to close it.
I have tried v-binding various data-bs-* properties to temporarily get the desired effect:
<template>
<div ref="modal" class="modal fade" :id="id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        :data-bs-backdrop="processing ? 'static' : 'true'"
        :data-bs-keyboard="processing ? 'static' : 'true'">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title h5">New Ladder</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close"
                        :data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
            <div ref="alert"></div>
            <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="mb-1">
                        <label for="addLadderName" class="form-label" hidden>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addLadderName" placeholder="Enter name"
                               v-model.trim="addLadderForm.name"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary me-auto"
                            :data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        {{ processing ? 'One moment please...' : 'Create' }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

But that doesn't seem to work; I can still close the modal during a hard-coded 10-second pause on the server side. It occurs to me that I could wire a bunch of the UI into to my own closeModal and do the appropriate checks within instead of relying on data-bs-dismiss. However, that seems like a duplication of existing work, especially since I'd have to figure out how to replicate whatever data-bs-backdrop="static" does.
I am using Vue 3.4.29 and Bootstrap 5.3.3, but not bootstrap-vue.

"I have tried v-binding various data-bs-* properties" - this doesn't serve a good purpose because you don't have reactivity. This is the reason for wrapper components to exist, or write them completely from scratch like bootstrap-vue. Could be something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/45048815/3731501 but I cannot confirm this.
