# How to disable ESC key on Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on a html page having an modal then if modal loads on page then if i press ESC key then modal closed , that is very unliking to me. how to prevent this.??
please note that modal using cakephp render.
i tried this , but not working

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) return false;
});
```

Comment: Where is the code of your modal? Post it here

Comment: are you usig jquery dialog or bootstrap modal? please post your code.

Comment: i am using bootstrap modal.

Comment: _i am using bootstrap modal._ Then you have to indicate this in the question as well as in tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable Escape Key for Twitter Bootstrap Modals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693079/how-to-disable-escape-key-for-twitter-bootstrap-modals)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add this attribute in your modal div

```
data-keyboard="false"
```

**Example**

```
<div id="myModal" data-keyboard="false">

</div>
```

Comment: Worked for Magento 2 Modal which uses jQuery.