# How to disable Escape Key for Twitter Bootstrap Dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, dropdown, keyevent

I do not want  Bootstrap Dropdowns to close when the ESC-Key is being pressed.

I tried the following snippet without any success:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    $(document).on("keydown", $button, function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code === 27) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

I found a [similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693079/how-to-disable-escape-key-for-twitter-bootstrap-modals), which is about disabling the Key for Bootstraps Modals. The solution for that seems to be `data-keyboard="false"`. Is there a similar solution for Dropdowns?

**Edit:**
See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hboLjzg9/1/)

Comment: add `return false;`  after prevent default. Then it should work.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this does not work either. the keydown event does not even seem to get fired.

Comment: can you show us your HTML? So, we can debugg your js code and find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use following:

```
$('#dropdown_id').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('keepopen')) {
      $(this).removeClass('keepopen')
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
  }
});
```

Add class 'keepopen' when you expect dropdown to close and want to prevent it. In my case it is typing in the input element inside the dropdown:

```
$('#input_id').on('keydown', function(e){
  if (e.which == 27) {
    $('#dropdown_id').addClass('keepopen');
  }
});
```