# How to disable Escape Key for Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

```
$('#datePicker').datepicker({
    language: "fr",
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    calendarWeeks: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    endDate: '+0d',
});
```

Comment: $('#datePicker').datepicker({
language: "fr",
backdrop: 'static',
keyboardNavigation: false,
calendarWeeks: true,
todayHighlight: true,
format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
endDate: '+0d',
   });

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693079/how-to-disable-escape-key-for-twitter-bootstrap-modals

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Escape Key for Twitter Bootstrap Modals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693079/how-to-disable-escape-key-for-twitter-bootstrap-modals)

Comment: Neither of those questions are even close to duplicates of this one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to [this library](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/)?

If that's the case, it looks like there isn't any option to disable the escape button.

I'd recommend using [Bootstrap datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) instead. It has more options, and if you only need the date and not the time, it can do that too.

To disable the `escape` key binding (along with keyboard navigation, since you had that disabled as well), you'd just do this:

```
$("#your-element").datetimepicker({
  keyBinds: {
    escape: null,
    up: null,
    down: null,
    right: null,
    left: null
  }
});
```

Comment: Great. Thank you :)

Comment: The datetimepicker of eonasdan is not maintained anymore and it is not compatible with bootstrap 4. However https://tempusdominus.github.io/ is a continuation of the former one so it is basically the same deal with the same syntax and everything but compatible with bootstrap 4.