# prevent bootstrap modal window from closing on form submission

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hi I'm using Bootstrap for the first time and I can't get my modal form to stay open on clicking the submit button. 
I've searched SO but all related questions deal with slightly different issues (example below).

[Disallow twitter bootstrap modal window from closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894339/disallow-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window-from-closing)

Comment: do you submit the form via ajax or is it just a normal submit form?

Comment: @Apostolov, thanks for the quick reply! I'm not using ajax. Ajax doesn't post back the page and since I do want to postback on submission, I thought I shouldn't.

Comment: @apostolov i have the same problem, and i'm using Ajax what should i do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

look at => http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

use

```
data-backdrop="static"
```

or

```
$("#yourModal").modal({"backdrop": "static"});
```

Edit1 :

on your link opening your modal ==>

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#yourModal').modal({'backdrop': 'static'});" class="btn btn-primary">yourModal</a>
```

Edit2 :

http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/39/

Comment: Hi @ZooL, thanks for your suggestions. I've tried both of them and, oddly enough, the JS works and the markup doesn't. However the JS route doesn't quite cut it because the modal window shows up on page load, rather than on link-click.

Comment: have you tried your edit at all? I've noticed you removed the double quotes, but I still believe it doesn't work because href has to be set to the modal window's id.

Comment: @dura you have to try. The onclick event occurs when you click on link.

Comment: I have tried it @ZooL. The window still closes on clicking the 'submit' button. I've tried to add the onclick event to that button but that doesn't work either.

Comment: thanks a lot for all your efforts. I had a play around with your jfiddle and it works. However, it also works (i.e. the modal window doesn't close on submit) if I remove the JS and add the original 'role' and 'data-toggle' of the bootstrap example. Let's move this to the chat perhaps.

Comment: @dura If it works, please valid the Answer. Maybe it will be useful for someone else.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it has been useful overall. However it hasn't solved my problem.

Comment: @ZooL It is bad practice to have JavaScript in an onclick attribute. Check out [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). You should update the answer to advise new programmers against this.

Comment: data-backdrop="static" this works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Remove the following:

```
data-dismiss = "modal"
```

From the button that should not close the dialog. After that, you can close the dialog by using $( "#TheDialogID" ).modal( "hide" ). Example:

```
<!--<SimpleModalBox>-->
<div class="modal fade" id="SimpleModalBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="SimpleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <!--<modal-dialog>-->
  <div class = "modal-dialog">

    <!--<modal-content>-->
    <div class = "modal-content">

      <div class = "modal-header">
        <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class = "modal-title" id = "SimpleModalLabel">Title for a simple modal</h4>
      </div>

      <div id="TheBodyContent" class = "modal-body">
        Put your content here
      </div>

      <div class = "modal-footer">
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Yes</button>
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" onclick="doSomethingBeforeClosing()">Don't close</button>
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--<modal-content>-->

  </div>
  <!--/modal-dialog>-->
</div>
<!--</SimpleModalBox>-->
```

Javascript code:

```
//#region Dialogs
function showSimpleDialog() {
  $( "#SimpleModalBox" ).modal();
}

function doSomethingBeforeClosing() {
  //Do something. For example, display a result:
  $( "#TheBodyContent" ).text( "Operation completed successfully" );

  //Close dialog in 3 seconds:
  setTimeout( function() { $( "#SimpleModalBox" ).modal( "hide" ) }, 3000 );
}
//#endregion Dialogs
```

Answer (score 13):

This is how I did in my program, hope it helps.

This is the button which triggers the modal. Here I have disabled the keyboard and mouse click outside the modal.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDivId"
                data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
```

This is the modal div, with a form and a submit button. Replace `...` with your modal content.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDivId" role="dialog">
 <form>
   ...
  <button type="submit" onClick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-success">
     Submit
  </button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Finally the function which triggers when you click submit button. Here `event.preventDefault();` will prevent the default action of form submit, so that the modal will remain.

```
function myFunction() {
    $("form").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "yoururl",
            type: "POST",
            data: yourData,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result)
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add multiple data and you want modal to stay open use

> - `<button type="button"></button>`

and If you want to close the modal after submitting data you must use

> - `<button type="submit"></button>`

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the similar problem where I use modal as a form so I cannot initially set `data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"` because I want the user to be able to close it as long as he has not submitted the form. Once he has submitted the form, I want to prevent him from closing the form modal. Here is how I can get around.

```
$('#modalForm').on('submit', function() {
  $(#modal).on('hide.bs.modal', function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }) 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to prevent bootstrap modal window from closing on form submission

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code only:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

and write your html code in update panel then remove data-dismiss="modal" from the button. Hope it works for you.

Comment: It would be great if you could add some explanation to your code. If you only write directives the learning effect is greatly reduced.

Comment: This what i want to say :
Explanation:

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
-<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
                aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
 <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="btn btn-primary form-control" />
 </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>