# Clicking on Twitter Bootsrap 3 Modal Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 to show a modal on top of a map with spots. I'd like users to be able to click on the spots on the map without the modal exiting.

I already have set the modal background to static so it doesn't quit when you click outside the modal but reducing it's z-index still doesn't allow the spots to be clicked on.

Anyone know how to do it, tried googling but seems like i'm the only one with this weird need

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood correctly, but do you just want to keep the modal open, even if a user clicks outside of the actual dialogue? If yes, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9894427/1206437) answer might help you. It says to change data-backdrop to static :

```
<a data-controls-modal="your_div_id" data-backdrop="static" href="#">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've already done that, what I now need is for the user to be able to click on the spots on the map without closing the static modal. Background clicking seems to be disabled even when I reduce the z-index of the modal div

Comment: Hm. Have you tried giving the modal background the css attribute pointer-events : none; ? I saw this idea on http://stackoverflow.com/a/4839672/1206437 . But it doesn't seem to be supported in IE at all.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution is to reduce the length of backdrop element which works for me because modal is not the left and map is on the right with both sharing equal status in terms of interest