# javascript bootstrap modal - cancel closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

my work is using javascript bootstrap 2.0.4

I'm looking for a way to cancel the modal from closing, by logic control.
but I can't find any details how to do this

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

something like .NET

```
OnWindowClosing(eventArguement) 
{ 
    if (shouldCancel) {
      eventArguement.Cancel = true; 
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/9894339/2454790

Comment: Try returning false in your function OnWindowClosing.

Comment: @Jahnux73 . no, the post looks like want to disable the closing, while i still allow it to close, but under certain condition, i want to abort the closing.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Look at here : [www.bootply.com/QTTDf3zRgV](http://www.bootply.com/QTTDf3zRgV)

In this exemple, if the checkbox is checked, then the modal can't be closed ( with js/jquery):

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e){
  if( $('#block').is(':checked') ) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     return false; 
   }
});
```

Comment: As @Affilnost says below, ```e.cancel()``` is not defined use ```e.stopImmediatePropagation()```

Comment: Works great with Bootstrap 3 as well.

Answer (score 5):

`e.cancel` is not defined and causes an error - that's why the solution above is working.

You should add `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

Here's a demo: http://www.bootply.com/o5jsyItQMm

Answer (score 4):

the solution you provided was not working so find this and its the perfect solution
referrence here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1202#issuecomment-48601320

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal.prevent', closeModalEvent);
/**
* allow popup to hide or not
* @param {type} e
* @returns {Boolean}
 */
function closeModalEvent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#block').is(':checked')) {
        $('#myModal').off('hide.bs.modal.prevent');
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm using *Bootstrap v4-alpha.6* and tying in to the `hide.bs.modal.prevent` event as you linked in [the github issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1202#issuecomment-48601320). This does indeed prevent the modal from closing, but the second time the user attempts to click outside the modal it logs an error to the console : `bootstrap.min.js Uncaught Error: Modal is transitioning`.

Comment: issue still persist ??

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is that “…prevent” construction in event name? (I know what is namespacing, but can’t find anything about prevent namespace)

Comment: @diesel94 The `.prevent` namespace is something they're adding so that they can remove just this specific event handler later. When you specify a namespace in the call to `.on()`, then you can use the same namespace in the call to `.off()`, without affecting any other handlers that are registered to the same event that _don't_ use that namespace.