# Disable click outside of bootstrap modal area to close modal

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am making a bootstrap website, with a couple of Bootstrap 'Modals'.
I'm trying to customize some of the default features.

Problem is this;
You can close the modal by clicking on the background.
Is there anyway to disable this feature?
On specifc modals only?

[Bootstrap modal page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: can you please tell me which event is called in this situation. $scope.ok , $scope.$dismiss i have implement for submit and abort but i don't know the event fired in this situation.

Answer (score 1198, accepted):

On Options chapter, in the page you linked, you can see the `backdrop` option. Passing this option with value `'static'` will prevent closing the modal.
As @PedroVagner pointed on comments, you also can pass `{keyboard: false}` to prevent closing the modal by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

If you opening the modal by js use:

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

If you are using data attributes, use:

```
 <button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    Launch demo modal
 </button>`
```

Comment: is there a way to keep the background able to register the clicks for other controls but just not close the modals ?

Comment: @mystikacid You should ask a new question for that. It will be better to help you with your problem and other users searching a similar solution.

Comment: @Doguita : Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000898/bootstrap-modal-disable-close-on-backdrop-click-without-disabling-the-backgrou

Comment: Had a simple but irritating problem, make sure you place the jquery line before `$('#modal').modal('show');` Hope this helps!

Comment: cwiggo you don't use modal $('#modal').modal('show'); - you just use .modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}) - without any show or toggle command

Comment: Bootstrap 3 documentation with these options: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-options

Comment: Bootstrap 5 requires the `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target` attributes.

Answer (score 204):

This is the easiest one

You can define your modal behavior, defining data-keyboard and data-backdrop.

```
<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade in" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Passing in the options in JS directly just didn't work for me for some reason (version 3.3.7). If anyone else corroborates, I might open an issue with the Bootstrap team.

Comment: At first, using js version didn't work for me too because I was setting everything after I opened the modal. You should do this "$('#modalForm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });" before this "$('#modalForm').modal('show');". But for me, the best answer is from @ಅನಿಲ್

Comment: This worked for me. Putting the `data-backdrop="static"` option on the modal definition, not the trigger button that opens the modal  as specified in other answers, worked for me.

Comment: I've solved using only data-backdrop="static". You can see here : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_backdrop_data&stacked=h

Answer (score 107):

You can use an attribute like this: `data-backdrop="static"` or with javascript:

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false  // to prevent closing with Esc button (if you want this too)
})
```

See this answer too: [Disallow twitter bootstrap modal window from closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894339)

Comment: <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade in" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">  this is best answer.

Answer (score 49):

In my application, I am using the below piece of code to show Bootstrap modal via jQuery.

```
 $('#myModall').modal({
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: true, 
                        show: true
                });
```

Comment: This is good answer because this code will work only when modal is open.

Answer (score 35):

You can use

```
$.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.DEFAULTS.backdrop = 'static';
$.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.DEFAULTS.keyboard =  false;
```

to change the default behavior.

Comment: Great answer, as it handles the situation for all modals.

Comment: In bootstrap v4, the syntax is:
$.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.Default.backdrop = 'static';

Comment: @HarisurRehman The asker wanted it to be enforced on specific modals though...

Comment: @DanielWu depends on how you read the question.

Answer (score 34):

Put this code in the first block of your modal html

**Bootstrap 4.x**

`data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"`

**Boostrap 5.x**

`data-bs-keyboard="false" data-bs-backdrop="static"`

Example:

```
<div id="modal-user" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-keyboard="false" data-bs-backdrop="static">
```

Docs bootstrap 5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#options

> Includes a modal-backdrop element. Alternatively, specify `static` for a backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.

Comment: Put this on the same div where you put class="modal"

Answer (score 15):

Checkout This ::

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popup").modal({
        show: false,
        backdrop: 'static'
    });
    
    $("#click-me").click(function() {
       $("#popup").modal("show");             
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
    <body>
        <div class="modal" id="popup" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3>Standard Selectpickers</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <select class="selectpicker" data-container="body">
                    <option>Mustard</option>
                    <option>Ketchup</option>
                    <option>Relish</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a id="click-me" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</a> 
    </body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14):

There are two ways to disable click outside of bootstrap model area to close modal-

1. **using javascript**

   ```
   $('#myModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
   });
   ```
2. **using data attribute in HTML tag**

   ```
   data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" //write this attributes in that button where you click to open the modal popup.
   ```

Answer (score 13):

Use this CSS for Modal and modal-dialog

```
.modal{
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modal-dialog{
    pointer-events: all;
 }
```

This can resolve your problem in Modal

Comment: Best option if you would like to turn it off for every modal in application

Comment: But it turns off browser scroll :(

Comment: The best solution to get rid of backdrop static effect when clicking outside!

Answer (score 12):

Another option if you do not know if the modal has already been opened or not yet and you need to configure the modal options:

> Bootstrap 3.4

```
var $modal = $('#modal');
var keyboard = false; // Prevent to close by ESC
var backdrop = 'static'; // Prevent to close on click outside the modal

if(typeof $modal.data('bs.modal') === 'undefined') { // Modal did not open yet
    $modal.modal({
        keyboard: keyboard,
        backdrop: backdrop
    });
} else { // Modal has already been opened
    $modal.data('bs.modal').options.keyboard = keyboard;
    $modal.data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = backdrop;

    if(keyboard === false) { 
        $modal.off('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal'); // Disable ESC
    } else { // 
        $modal.data('bs.modal').escape(); // Resets ESC
    }
}
```

> Bootstrap 4.3+

```
var $modal = $('#modal');
var keyboard = false; // Prevent to close by ESC
var backdrop = 'static'; // Prevent to close on click outside the modal

if(typeof $modal.data('bs.modal') === 'undefined') { // Modal did not open yet
    $modal.modal({
        keyboard: keyboard,
        backdrop: backdrop
    });
} else { // Modal has already been opened
    $modal.data('bs.modal')._config.keyboard = keyboard;
    $modal.data('bs.modal')._config.backdrop = backdrop;

    if(keyboard === false) { 
        $modal.off('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal'); // Disable ESC
    } else { // 
        $modal.data('bs.modal').escape(); // Resets ESC
    }
}
```

Change options to _config

Comment: for Bootstrap 4 + should it be `_setEscapeEvent()` instead of `.escape()`?

Comment: @IvanBacher Works to me using .escape()

Answer (score 8):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
```

try this,During my application development ...I also met the trouble that default values for a model attribute => `data-keyboard="true"`,
          => `data-backdrop="non static"`

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 7):

The solution that work for me is the following:

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

backdrop: disabled the click outside event

keyboard: disabled the scape keyword event

Answer (score 7):

This solution worked for me:

```js
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

with
`data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"`

in the button witch launch the Modal

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="customer_bill_gen"
  data-keyboard="false"
  data-backdrop="static"
>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this if you want to disable the outer click for all modals using jQuery. Add this script to your Javascript after jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('[data-toggle="modal"]').each(function () {
       jQuery(this).attr('data-backdrop','static');
       jQuery(this).attr('data-keyboard','false');
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, as written. None of the other solutions did.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to change default:

for bootstrap 3.x:

```
$.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.DEFAULTS.backdrop = 'static';
$.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.DEFAULTS.keyboard =  false;
```

for bootstrap 4.x and 5.x:

```
$.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.Default.backdrop = 'static';
$.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.Default.keyboard =  false;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **@ng-bootstrap** use the following:

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss'],
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private ngbModal: NgbModal
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  openModal(exampleModal: any, $event: any) {
    this.ngbModal.open(exampleModal, {
      size: 'lg', // set modal size
      backdrop: 'static', // disable modal from closing on click outside
      keyboard: false, // disable modal closing by keyboard esc
    });
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<div (click)="openModal(exampleModal, $event)"> </div>
    <ng-template #exampleModal let-modal>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Test modal</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body p-3">
            <form action="">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="">Test field 1</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="">Test field 2</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-right pt-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="modal.dismiss('Close')">Close</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary ml-1">Save</button>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

This code was tested on angular 9 using:

1. "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
2. "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",

Answer (score 2):

For Bootstrap `4.x`, you can do like this :

```
$('#modal').data('bs.modal')._config.backdrop = 'static';
$('#modal').data('bs.modal')._config.keyboard = false;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Also, please make the addtional insight more obvious which your answer contributes in addition to existing answers, like the one by @MoinUddin

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR

`backdrop: 'static'`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-options

> specify `static` for a backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click.

Answer (score 1):

none of these solutions worked for me.

I have a terms and conditions modal that i wanted to force people to review before continuing...the defaults "static" and "keyboard" as per the options made it impossible to scroll down the page as the terms and conditions are a few pages log, static was not the answer for me.

So instead i went to unbind the the click method on the modal, with the following i was able to get the desired effect.

`$('.modal').off('click');`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can Disallow closing of #signUp (This should be the id of the modal) modal when clicking outside of modal.
As well as on ESC button.
jQuery('#signUp').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    jQuery(this).data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';// For outside click of modal.
    jQuery(this).data('bs.modal').options.keyboard = false;// For ESC button.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `modal-dialog` that's why my close modal wasn't working properly.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this without using JQuery, like so:

```
<div id="myModal">

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
modal.backdrop = "static";
modal.keyboard = false;
```

Answer (score -2):

Add the below css as per you want your screen width.

```
@media (min-width: 991px){
    .modal-dialog {
        margin: 0px 179px !important;
    }
}
```