# Bootstrap modal : Disable close on backdrop click without disabling the background controls

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How can the modal be prevented from closing on a background click and still have the clicks register to work with the rest of the controls on the screen ?

Using the static method

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

disables the entire background.

Edit : 
My exact problem is this - I have different buttons on the screen and each of them have to show a popup on double click. Now, when I open a popup, I may also want to open another popup without closing the first one. If I make the backdrop static, clicking other buttons doesn't work and if I don't make it static, opening the second closes the first one. How do I enable opening multiple popups at a time ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give some insight as to what you're trying to accomplish by doing this? I think it would help get you some better answers

Answer (score 1):

Add this in style sheet, make sure it override default bootstrap modal values.

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
    opacity: 0 !important;
    z-index: -1050 !important;
}
```

OR

```
.modal-backdrop {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Working Example

```css
.modal {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(25%) !important;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(25%) !important;
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(25%) !important;
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(25%) !important;
}
.modal-backdrop {
     display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="static">Open Modal</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" data-backdrop="static">Open Modal 2</button>
<label>This is a text and can be selected for copying</label>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">This is Modal Header 2</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: Modal position change css is just for demo purpose.