# How can i make my website background greyed out when I a popup appears?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a list of users, I want to edit my code that when I click on a user, a popup appears containing the user information while the background gets greyed out. How can I do this?

Comment: It's a very broad question, but you would want to change the background colour of the `body` or `.container` programmatically when the modal is opened.

Comment: A common solution is to create a fixed/static div that completely covers the screen with a translucent black background. If you already have a popup/modal system in place, you could just use the container of the pop-up. [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

Comment: I think you mean the option keyboard: false  You can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207377/disable-click-outside-of-bootstrap-modal-area-to-close-modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Angular, you can refer to [this](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap:

```
$('#myModal').modal({
   backdrop: 'static',
   keyboard: false
});
```

For jquery:

```
$('#myModal').dialog({modal:true});
```