# How can I disable a website using jQuery or similar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website that has merged with another. It is a high ranking website so instead of using a redirect or similar I would like to keep the website online as is so that it does not affect SEO.

I want it so that when users visit the website it appears grayed out and a central box is shown with a message saying that the website has moved to `www.newsite.com` and they are not able to click any buttons etc. on the page.

Is it possible using jQuery or similar?

Comment: Simply take a screenshot, fade it out, and use it as a background image.

Comment: i fear that if you do what's described, that high SEO will quickly vanish

Comment: JQueryUI Dialog will do this nicely

Comment: HTTP 301 will allow the SEO to move in theory.

Answer (score 6):

This is possible with jQuery modal, but to be quite honest your best bet really is to issue a permanent redirect (301) to the new site.  You can likewise go to each of the major search engines and use their webmaster tools to indicate the site has moved.  Your SEO ranking might dip briefly but the search engines really do recognize the fact that sites and content move these days, and the ranking won't be permanently affected.

Comment: So the website it is redirected to would pick up the rankings even if the content is not exactly the same?

Comment: Your SEO rank gets constantly re-evaluated based on a lot of factors (most of which are content related).  What I'm describing is a way to specifically not make your rank suffer due to moving the URL.

Comment: It's worth noting that the best case scenario here is actually if each page on the old site has a 1:1 match on the new site, and performs the 301 redirect to its counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this however you like. JavaScript is probably not needed here. Create a simple modal, and style it in such a way that it looks how you have envisioned.

There are jQuery plugins to do this kind of thing, but honestly that's going to be more work to hook up and create more overhead than you would just making your own.

If you need some CSS help to accomplish this, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's possible to use a modal in Bootstrap that cannot be closed? Also CSS would be great :o)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894339/disallow-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window-from-closing

Answer (score 0):

You can hide Everything in body and append a div and style it like an modal or something as you like

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 node  = $("<div id='modal'>Site has been Moved moved etc.. </div>")
$("body").append(node);
  $("body *").not("modal").hide();


});
```

css

```
    #modal{

    /*style modal here */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing what you say will likely damage the SEO, however is possible with some simple css an jquery as long as the user has scripting active.  CSS and HTML can achieve the majority of what you want without the need for Jquery or scripting.

A properly implemented 301 redirect will ensure google maps across and acknowledges the movements of pages from one domain to another.  BUt you need to do this properly.

Comment: Google knows that I won't allow users to close a modal?