# ajax stop bootstrap modal box from closing when user clicks submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

This is a bit of a tricky problem to explain but here goes:

I would like to display results inside a bootstrap modalbox, doing the following:

[image]

1. Selectbox1-->populates-->SelectBox2-->populates-->Selectbox3
2. Get values from selectboxes when user clicks submit
3. Query database with selectbox values
4. Display result in modal box

**My problem**

Everything is working however w**hen user clicks submit the modalbox closes**, when I open the modalbox again the result is inside the modalbox

***HOW CAN I GET THE MODALBOX TO NOT CLOSE WHEN USER CLICKS SUBMIT?***

```
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
      <script type="text/javascript">
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  var formData = $(this).serialize();
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'functionTest.php',
    data: formData,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#resultForm').replaceWith(data);

    }

  });
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(".sport").change(function()
 {
  var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;

  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_sport.php",
   dataType : 'html',
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
      $(".tournament").html(html);
   } 
   });
  });


 $(".tournament").change(function()
 {
  var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;

  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_round.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".round").html(html);
   } 
   });
  });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>

         <center>
<div>
<label>Sport :</label> 
<form method="post" id="resultForm" name="resultForm">
<select name="sport" class="sport">
<option selected="selected">--Select Sport--</option>
<?php
    include('connect.php');
 $sql="SELECT distinct sport_type FROM events";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['sport_type']; ?>"><?php echo $row['sport_type']; ?></option>
        <?php
 } 
?>
</select>

<label>Tournamet :</label> <select name="tournament" class="tournament">
<option selected="selected">--Select Tournament--</option>
</select>


<label>Round :</label> <select name="round" class="round">
<option selected="selected">--Select Round--</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="View Picks" name="submit" />
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo  $tour = $_POST['tournament'];
 echo $round = $_POST['round'];
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894339/disallow-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window-from-closing?rq=1 <-- Perhaps this can be helpful? you could change the submit button with an anchor and set its parameter like that question?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're missing a "return false;" in your form submit event handler:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  var formData = $(this).serialize();
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'functionTest.php',
    data: formData,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#resultForm').replaceWith(data);

    }

  });
  //Return false to cancel submit
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your solution, but try putting e.stopPropagation(); before e.preventDefault();

**UPDATE**

> Why is your Modal in the <head> part ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the class close from the button