# disable outside click when using BootstrapDialog.show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using BootstrapDialog.show for modals and I want the modal to persist even if there is a click or touch(mobile) event outside the modal ..setting  backdrop static works for html is not working for **BootstrapDialog.show**

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: 'Logout',
        message: "Do you want to Logout?",
        buttons: [{
            label: 'Cancel',
            action: function (dialog) {
                dialog.close();
            }
        }, {
            label: 'OK',
            action: function (dialog) {
                window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
                dialog.close();
                location.href = "login.html";
            }
        }]
    });
```

I want to disable outside click.

Comment: Basically you just need to update your markup with the data attribute `data-backdrop="static"`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894339/disallow-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window-from-closing) similar SO for more information

Comment: @n0m4d - The OP is not asking for bootstrap modal approach, BootstrapDialog is different from bootstrap modal.

Comment: Good point @DavidDomain! I missed the context, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You need to add `closable: false,` . Check out the [github example page](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) and look for **Dialog closable / unclosable**

Comment: thanks @DavidDomain it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `closable : false` to your Bootstrap Dialog.