# How to close modal popup only when pressing the cancel button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple modal and I was wondering how can I only allow the modal to be closed when clicking the "X" button or the cancel button. Now when the user clicks outside the modal area.
Here's my code:

```
 <div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disallow twitter bootstrap modal window from closing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894339/disallow-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window-from-closing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this..

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})
```

or directly put it in your div

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
```