# Prevent bootstrap model popup to close on pressing space key

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

the model popup gets closed when I press space or enter key from the keyboard. I am using `data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"` but still it is closing. I have also not used the `form` tag in the popup.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#keyboardModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="keyboardModal"
  data-backdrop="static"
  data-keyboard="false"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg-override">
    <div class="modal-content">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Could you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894339/disallow-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window-from-closing/25159755#25159755

Comment: hi, your code is working perfect, the issue your getting is if only you click the modal button and  before clicking somewhere in the page if you press enter or space your button is getting triggered so your modal is getting close and opening back.

Comment: I got your point but not getting how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#open_modal').click(function(){
$('html').bind('keydown', function(e)
{
   if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32 )
   {
      return false;
   }
});
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#keyboardModal" id="open_modal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="keyboardModal"
  data-backdrop="static"
  data-keyboard="false"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg-override">
    <div class="modal-content">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

hope this may help you.

Comment: it is not working. Just run your snippet and click on the launch demo model button and then press space key. you will find the model popup get closed.

Comment: is there any way to implement it in angular 7 ?

Comment: yes, you can, just convert jquery code to native angular code. it will work a charm,